# How to find out if there are intersections of lists in one SQL query

Tags: java, database, jpa

There is an entity Post that has field `List<String> tags`

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "posts_tags",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@Column(name = "tag", nullable = false)
private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is PostRepositoty that has method

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

@Query(
        """
          SELECT ...
        """
    )
    Page<Post> findAllByTagsContaining(List<String> tagsParam, Pageable pageable);


}
```

Is it possible to get all the posts that have in its tags list at least one element from tagsParam with one only query? Could you help me in this please?

Comment: You could concat the `tagsParam` list to a regex and use the corresponding function of your database. I can't say anything about the performance of this operation, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
It turned out to be much easier than I thought

`Page<Post> findAllByTagsIn(List<String> tagsParam, Pageable pageable);`